Is is possible to have a bitfield of struct or union type?
I want to have a struct with the size of 64 bits (one full data CAN frame).  In this struct I want to have 16 structs, each having the size of 4 bits.
I already have a working solution, but it is not all that handy to use.
typedef union {
    struct
    {
        uint8_t swStatusOn:1;
        uint8_t swStatusFlank:1;
        uint8_t swStatusDoubleclick:1;
        uint8_t swStatusReady:1;
    };
    uint8_t byte;
} ElInputSW;

typedef struct
{
    uint8_t sw_01A:4;
    uint8_t sw_01B:4;
    uint8_t sw_02A:4;
    uint8_t sw_02B:4;
    uint8_t sw_03A:4;
    uint8_t sw_03B:4;
    uint8_t sw_04A:4;
    uint8_t sw_04B:4;
    uint8_t sw_05A:4;
    uint8_t sw_05B:4;
    uint8_t sw_06A:4;
    uint8_t sw_06B:4;
    uint8_t sw_07A:4;
    uint8_t sw_07B:4;
    uint8_t sw_08A:4;
    uint8_t sw_08B:4;
} ElInputsSW1;

...
ElInputsSW1 foo;
ElInputSW* baa;

baa = (ElInputSW*)&foo.sw_01A;
baa->swStatusOn = 1;


In case I want to access swStatusOn of sw_01A in ElInputsSW1m I have to cast it.  I would like to do the following:
typedef union {
    struct
    {
        uint8_t swStatusOn:1;
        uint8_t swStatusFlank:1;
        uint8_t swStatusDoubleclick:1;
        uint8_t swStatusReady:1;
    };
    uint8_t byte;
} ElInputSW;

typedef struct
{
    ElInputSW sw_01A:4;
    ElInputSW sw_01B:4;
    ElInputSW sw_02A:4;
    ElInputSW sw_02B:4;
    ElInputSW sw_03A:4;
    ElInputSW sw_03B:4;
    ElInputSW sw_04A:4;
    ElInputSW sw_04B:4;
    ElInputSW sw_05A:4;
    ElInputSW sw_05B:4;
    ElInputSW sw_06A:4;
    ElInputSW sw_06B:4;
    ElInputSW sw_07A:4;
    ElInputSW sw_07B:4;
    ElInputSW sw_08A:4;
    ElInputSW sw_08B:4;
} ElInputsSW1;

This will not compile. the bitfields have invalid type.
Is there a way to make it work?

As a side note, even with the uint8_t version, is that the order of bitfields in the storage unit is implementation-defined, so using bitfields to pack/unpack data for external use isn't reliably portable.

I've lost count on how many posts I've made on SO explaining why you shouldn't use bit-fields for any purpose, but particularly not for data packet or hardware register mapping. Writing this code with bitwise-operators and named macros will be far safer, cleaner and even portable. There's two paths you can take here: either "I want clean, smooth, readable code" or "I want to create problems for the heck of it".

a struct with the size of 64 bits AKA uint64_t.  Then deal with endianness.

writing clean, smooth and readable code is strong argument. @Lundin, but I have fixed Can-frame I can't change. I could implement get / set functions to read/write from and into the Can-frame but I don't like the boiler code.

@DP_C msg[0] = sw_01A(123) | sw_01B(456); msg[1] = sw_02A(789) | sw_02B(x) and so on. That's 8 lines of code which is both fast and readable. The chances of code repetition are slim if the lines are all indented and lined up underneath one another - in fact that increases the chances of spotting typos and copy/paste errors.

Not in portable, standard C, and not even using extensions available in commonly-used compilers.  The standard doesn’t even guarantee that a bitfield can have any other type than _Bool, signed int or unsigned int (with optional qualifiers); though it also allows for “some other implementation-defined type”, most common compilers only accept non-atomic integer types.
It is probably more idiomatic to use macros to name individual bits within a bit mask:
#define SW_STATUS_ON               1
#define SW_STATUS_FLANK            2
#define SW_STATUS_READY            4
#define SW_STATUS_DOUBLECLICK      8

// […]

ElInputsSW1 foo;
foo.sw_01A |= SW_STATUS_ON;

In your example, you could even use uint64_t for the whole frame of data and not use structs at all:
#define SW_STATUS_ON(i)            (UINT64_C(1) << ((i) * 4))
#define SW_STATUS_FLANK(i)         (UINT64_C(2) << ((i) * 4))
#define SW_STATUS_READY(i)         (UINT64_C(4) << ((i) * 4))
#define SW_STATUS_DOUBLECLICK(i)   (UINT64_C(8) << ((i) * 4))

#define SW_01A   0
#define SW_02A   1
#define SW_03A   2
// [etc.]

typedef uint64_t ElInputsSW1;

// […]

ElInputsSW1 foo;
foo |= SW_STATUS_ON(SW_01A);

Your solution using a pointer cast does not work either, by the way.  Forming a pointer to a bitfield is undefined behaviour, and not of the “benign” kind that tends to work fine in practice, but rather of the kind that is often outright rejected at compile time, or triggers bad behaviour very quickly.  A pointer is a memory address at byte granularity at best, while distinct bitfields can share a byte and would therefore need finer addressing.  As such, the pointer formed, if the compiler allows such an operation at all, is not guaranteed to point to the correct place.

I thougt about using marcos but I would need a second macro to write a value. Plus there is no dummy protection in case you write on a variable which is unfit for the use.

Thanks for all the recommendations and hints.
The main problem with my first attempt boils down to the fact that the smallest addressable varable has 8bits.
But against all good practice: I found a solution.
typedef union
{
    struct {
        uint8_t On:1;
        uint8_t Flank:1;
        uint8_t Doubleclick:1;
        uint8_t Ready:1;
        uint8_t reserve:4;
    }A;
    struct
    {
        uint8_t reserve:4;
        uint8_t On:1;
        uint8_t Flank:1;
        uint8_t Doubleclick:1;
        uint8_t Ready:1;
    }B;
}ElInputSW_;

typedef union
{
    struct
    {
        ElInputSW_ sw1;
        ElInputSW_ sw2;
        ElInputSW_ sw3;
        ElInputSW_ sw4;
        ElInputSW_ sw5;
        ElInputSW_ sw6;
        ElInputSW_ sw7;
        ElInputSW_ sw8;
    };
    uint8_t data[8];
}ElInputsSw_;

...
  ElInputsSw_ test0;
  test0.sw1.A.On = 1;
  test0.sw1.B.On = 1;

I had to reorganise the struct, but the information sits on the same bits.
I'm very sure everyone dislikes this equally. Me included.
my use case:
sending:
HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage(hcan, TxHeader, test0.data, TxMailbox)

receiving:
HAL_CAN_GetRxMessage(hcan, CAN_RX_FIFO0, RxHeader, test0.data)

With this solution I don't have to implement a fuction to write the information from the can-frame into a proper struct (and the other way around).


I want to have a struct with the size of 64 bits ....
In this struct I want to have 16 structs, each having the size of 4 bits.

Not possible in standard C.
